# Vertical style accordion using vaadin

Tags: coding-style, accordion, vaadin

I am using vaadin framework, I can use the `com.vaadin.ui.Accordion` library for Accordion.
By default it appears in horizontal style. Is there any idea of using this style in vertical form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Accordion.html:

> An accordion is a component similar to a TabSheet, but with a vertical orientation and the selected component presented between tabs

Do you mean you want it to be horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: Go ahead and try it.  By default it is vertical.

Comment: I disagree. Technically and basing on the API, it might be related. But clearly, for a tabsheet, the navigation buttons are separated from the content, which is not the case for an accordion. An accordeon also "moves" the buttons when changing "tab".

Answer (score 1):

An Accordion *is* a TabSheet, a subclass of TabSheet, as [documented](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Accordion.html) in the API.

TabSheet is meant for horizontal use, Accordion for vertical use.

TabSheet screenshot:

[image]

Accordion screenshot:

[image]